# How can I get around declaring an unused variable in a list comprehension?

Tags: python, list-comprehension

If I have a list comprehension (for example) like this:

```
['' for x in myList]
```

Effectively making a new list that has an empty string for every element in a list, I never use the `x`. Is there a cleaner way of writing this so I don't have to declare the unused `x` variable?

Comment: Inspired by this question, I created a youtube tutorial covering unused variables in list comprehensions  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=cZb5aFcpsAs

Comment: Relevant: [PEP 640: Unused variable syntax](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0640/) (currently in "Draft" status), which proposes allowing `?` as placeholder.

Answer (score 148, accepted):

`_` is a standard placeholder name for ignored members in a for-loop and tuple assignment, e.g.

```
['' for _ in myList]

[a+d for a, _, _, d, _ in fiveTuples]
```

BTW your list could be written without list comprehension (assuming you want to make a list of  immutable members like strings, integers etc.).

```
[''] * len(myList)
```

Comment: The latter must be accompanied by a huge warning that it doesn't do the expected thing for mutable objects.

Comment: @Mohit: `a=[[]]*4;a[0].append(5);print(a)`

Comment: @Ramy: Mohit posted an explanation but it was deleted :S Anyway, check Notes 2 in http://docs.python.org/py3k/library/stdtypes.html#sequence-types-str-bytes-bytearray-list-tuple-range.

Comment: @Ramy, Python maintains the same reference for same object in memory.

Comment: Does it matter if I'm doing nested `for` loops, for example? Or if inside `for _ in range(...)` I want to say `_, var = f(x)`?  Will it get confused between the two `_` variables?

Comment: @EricAuld it doesn't matter, the for loop doesn't rely on the variable name (`for i in range(3): for i in range(3): print('.')` will always print 9 dots). The inner variable will for sure shadow the outer one, but you're not supposed to read `_`.

Comment: __ (double underscore) works the same if you don't want to ruin the possibility of using _ to mean last output in the interpreter

Answer (score 19):

No. As the Zen puts it: Special cases aren't special enough to break the rules. The special case being loops not using the items of the thing being iterated and the rule being that there's a "target" to unpack to.

You can, however, use `_` as variable name, which is usually understood as "intentionally unused" (even  PyLint etc. knows and respect this).

Comment: PyLint however complains that `C: 10,24: Invalid variable name "_" (invalid-name)` unless you add it to `good-names` in your `.pylintrc`.

Answer (score 13):

It turns out that using `dummy*` (starting word is dummy) as the variable name does the same trick as `_`. `_` is a known standard and it would be better to use meaningful variable names. So you can use `dummy`, `dummy1`, `dummy_anything`. By using these variable names `PyLint` won't complain.

Comment: I indeed prefer this approach. it remains meaningful.

Answer (score 2):

Add the following comment after the for loop on the same line:

#pylint: disable=unused-variable

```
for i in range(100): #pylint: disable=unused-variable
```

Answer (score 1):

If you need to name your arguments (in case, for example, when writing mocks that don't use certain arguments that are referenced by name), you can add this shortcut method:

```
def UnusedArgument(_):
  pass
```

and then use it like this

```
def SomeMethod(name_should_remain):
  UnusedArgument(name_should_remain)
```

Answer (score 0):

The generator objects don't actually use the variables. So something like

```
list(('' for x in myList))
```

should do the trick. Note that x is not defined as a variable outside of the generator comprehension.

Answer (score 0):

You can also prepend a variable name with `_` if you prefer giving the variable a human readable name. For example you can use `_foo`, `_foo1`, `_anything` and PyLint won't complain. In a for loop, it would be like:

```py
for _something in range(10):
    do_something_else()
```

edit: Add example

Answer (score 0):

A verbose way is:

```
newList = []
while len(newList) < len(mylist):
    newList.append('')
```

You avoid declaring an used variable this way.

Also you can append both mutable and immutable objects (like dictionaries) into `newList`.

Another thing for python newbies like me, '_', 'dummy' are a bit disconcerting.

Answer (score 0):

**Try it, it's simple:**

```
# Use '_' instead of the variable
for _ in range(any_number):
    do_somthing()
```

Answer (score -1):

Comment to [How can I get around declaring an unused variable in a for loop?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477134/how-can-i-get-around-declaring-an-unused-variable-in-a-for-loop/5477153#5477153) (Ran out of comment size)

Python maintains the same reference for the object created. (irrespective of mutability),for example,

```
In [1]: i = 1

In [2]: j = 1

In [3]: id(i)
Out[3]: 142671248

In [4]: id(j)
Out[4]: 142671248
```

You, can see both i and j, refer to the same object in memory.What happens, when we change the value of one immutable variable.

```
In [5]: j = j+1

In [6]: id(i)
Out[6]: 142671248

In [7]: id(j)
Out[7]: 142671236
```

you can see j now starts to point a new location, (where 2 is stored), and i still points to location where 1 is stored.
While evaluating,

```
j = j+1
```

The value is picked from 142671248, calculated(if not already cached), and put at a new location 142671236. j is made to point to
the new location. In simpler terms a new copy made everytime an immutable variable is modified.

### Mutability

Mutable objects act little different in this regard. When the value pointed by

```
In [16]: a = []

In [17]: b = a

In [18]: id(a)
Out[18]: 3071546412L

In [19]: id(b)
Out[19]: 3071546412L
```

Both a and b point to the same memory location.

```
In [20]: a.append(5)
```

Memory location pointed by a is modified.

```
In [21]: a
Out[21]: [5]

In [22]: b
Out[22]: [5]

In [23]: id(a)
Out[23]: 3071546412L

In [24]: id(b)
Out[24]: 3071546412L
```

Both a and b, still point to the same memory location. In other word, mutable variables act of the same memory location pointed by the variable, instead of making a copy of the value pointed by the variable, like in immutable variable case.