# Disregarding python variables

Tags: python, variables

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [how can i get around declaring an unused variable in a for loop](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477134/how-can-i-get-around-declaring-an-unused-variable-in-a-for-loop)

In Python, particularly with a for-loop, is there a way to not create a variable if you don't care about it, ie the `i` in this example which isn't needed:

```
for i in range(10):
    print('Hello')
```

Comment: You make a good point! It was a frustratingly hard thing to search for.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, but often you will find that `_` is used instead:

```
for _ in range(10):
    print('Hello')
```

You only have to be careful when you use [`gettext`](http://docs.python.org/library/gettext.html).

Comment: Does the _ have a particular meaning, or is it actually for this purpose?

Comment: @Dean: Your question illustrates why you should never use this variable name :)

Comment: @Dean Barnes It has no particular meaning. Since `_` is also a magic variable in the interactive shell (always contains the result of the last expression), it's well-suited as a dummy variabnle.

Comment: @Dean Take a look at this question: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1538832/is-this-single-underscore-a-built-in-variable-in-python)

Comment: @Dean: It is not special, it is a valid [identifier](http://docs.python.org/reference/lexical_analysis.html#identifiers)

Comment: @Dean, there is nothing special about '_', but it is a common convention in Python to use it in this manner for throwaway variables.

Answer (score 5):

A for-loop always creates a name.  If you don't want to use it, just make this clear by its name, for example call it `dummy`.  Some people also use the name `_` for an unused variable, but I wouldn't recommend this name because it tends to confuse people, making them think this is some special kind of syntax.  Furthermore, it clashes with the name `_` in the interactive interpreter and with the common gettext alias of the same name.

Comment: +1 for mentioning possible gettext conflict

Answer (score 4):

I've seen people use `_` as a throw-away variable. I tend to just use `i` and not use it.

Answer (score 3):

Just use a variable name you don't care about. This could be `dummy` or the often-seen `_`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes:

```
from __future__ import print_function
print(*['Hello']*10, sep='\n')
```

But you should prefer the `for` loop for readability

Comment: It didn't click, but print('Hello\n' * 10, end='') would also work. Good thinking :)

Answer (score 2):

Try this little arabesqsue.

```
print "Hello\n"*10
```