# Python: How to make each term of an array repeat, with the same terms grouped together

Tags: python, arrays, list

My array is `[A,B,C]` and I want to multiply it so I can make the array `[A,A,A,B,B,B,C,C,C]`

Comment: The number to multiply it, will it be same for each element, like 3 or 5 etc.. ?

Comment: You can just write a for loop to iterate over this and then put the elements.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

you can chain the results of `itertools.repeat`:

```
import itertools
list(itertools.chain.from_iterable(itertools.repeat(x,3) for x in ["A","B","C"]))
```

result:

```
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

this solution minimizes the loops & the temporary lists (none is created)

Answer (score 4):

Use `zip`

```
>>> l = ['A','B','C']
>>> [e for sl in zip(*[l]*3) for e in sl]
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Or you can use `itertools.chain` to flatten the list produced by `zip`

```
>>> list(chain(*zip(*[l]*3)))
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Comment: in that case use `list(chain.from_iterable(zip(*[l]*3)))` avoids star unpacking of zip return value

Answer (score 3):

If not opposed to `numpy`, you can create an array of your original list repeated using `np.repeat`:

```
>>> import numpy as np
>>> np.repeat(['A','B','C'], 3)
array(['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C'],
      dtype='<U1')
```

If so desired, you can convert that back to a list as opposed to an `np.array` using `tolist`:

```
>>> np.repeat(['A','B','C'], 3).tolist()
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make use of list comprehensions:

```
>>> [item for item in ['A', 'B', 'C'] for _ in range(3)]
['A', 'A', 'A', 'B', 'B', 'B', 'C', 'C', 'C']
```

Comment: `for mul in range(0,3)` => `for mul in range(3)` is shorter

Comment: `for mul in range(3)` => `for _ in range(3)` is shorter-er. :P Since `mul` is [unused](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477134/how-can-i-get-around-declaring-an-unused-variable-in-a-for-loop/5477153#5477153).

Comment: don't you dare overgolfing me :)

Answer (score 2):

Not quite as clean as the other answers, but this should work too:

```
test = ['A','B','C']

def repeat_elements(currentArray, numRepeat):
    newArray = []
    for elem in currentArray:
        for x in range(numRepeat):
            newArray.append(elem)

    return newArray

print repeat_elements(test, 3)
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you regardless of how long the list is.

```
array = ['A','B','C']
new_array = []
for i in array:
    new_array += i * 3
```

(This works as long as you're not using integers in place of characters/strings as array elements)

Comment: The other option, if sorting isn't an issue, is to simply do: new_array = array * 3

Comment: I think this solution will fail if he uses integers in place of characters/strings as array elements

Comment: You're right. I've edited my answer to reflect that.

Comment: The problem I found with this (I already tried this) was that you have to write [i] and it makes an array of arrays instead of one array.