# How to avoid an "unused variable" warning when counting lines in a file?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to count the lines in a file but the intellisense is throwing a warning that the variable `line` is never used. This makes me assume there is a better way of doing this.

Please note I am **not** asking how to efficiently count the rows!

```
with open(FILE, newline='') as f:
  reader = csv.reader(f)
  for line in reader:
    counter = counter + 1
```

Is there a better way of doing this?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to get line count of a large file cheaply in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/845058/how-to-get-line-count-of-a-large-file-cheaply-in-python)

Comment: @Brian it does not. It's not even close to what I asked.

Comment: My apologies. Given the title of your question "Counting lines in a file", I read "this" as meaning "how to count lines in a file", not "how to name unused variables". Anyhow, the correct duplicate would be https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477134/how-can-i-get-around-declaring-an-unused-variable-in-a-for-loop

Comment: @Brian I edited the title to prevent confusion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The idiomatic way of indicating a variable is unused is to use `_`.

```
  for _ in reader:
    # ...
```

Comment: Thanks. I will accept this as the answer soon as I can.

Comment: More idiomatic: `counter += 1`