# Making the number of executions of a for-loop depending on a variable

Tags: python-3.x, for-loop

As you probably already figured by my question, I am pretty new to programming which is why this question is so basic. But I couldn't really find a question that had an answer to my problem so I thought I might just ask. I have a list that contains integers that I wanted to compare to each other so they can be sorted from highest to lowest. Now for that I wanted to use a for-loop that is executed exactly as many times as there are integers in my list. How do I do that? I tried:

```
for len(a):    # (a is my list)
    *code*
```

Thought it is returning me an error, saying that it couldn't be assigned to the function call. I am not sure why :/ . I hope you can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```py
for i in range(len(a)):
```

is the usual way; the [official Python tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/controlflow.html#the-range-function) is a good place to start for understanding `range()`, and the fact that the loop is executed as many times as there are elements in your list *when you first entered the loop*

Comment: Thank you :) what if I have no usage for the variable i tho? Should I just leave it out?

Comment: @Lenni4000 Yes, the standard idiom in Python is [to use a single underscore for unused loop variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5477134/how-can-i-get-around-declaring-an-unused-variable-in-a-for-loop)

Comment: Thanks. I appreciate it :)